# Shiny application to initialise and terminate database connection

Tags: r, database, connection, shiny

My requirement is to build a Shiny application that connects once and only once to the database, when the application is launched. If the database times out the connection, that is fine. Similarly, when a user closes the window, the database connection should be closed. This Shiny application has a Submit button that will do a CRUD operation depending on other form inputs.

In what section of a Shiny application can I handle application launch and termination so that I can connect and close database connection correspondingly?

Comment: Thanks. That is an interesting one.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your database at the application launch in `global.R`. This will make available the DB connection to all the application sessions. But maybe you will be more interested to create the connection with the DB each time a new session starts, for that you can create the connection inside your `server` function in `server.R`. To close the database you can use `session$onSessionEnded`. See the sample code below.

```js
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # code to connect to DB

  # ... 

  # code to disconnect the DB
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    # this funtion will be execute when session ends
    # like when the user closes the window
    # disconnect DB...

  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will explore.